# Hello World Google Home app not working in simulation

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

Getting errors saying this doesn't work in simulation?

https://console.actions.google.com/project/helloworld-4e256/simulator

I'm following this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYkUEunn9iA

[image]

```
{
    "response": "Sorry, this action is not available in simulation",
    "audioResponse": "//NExAAQQ...",
    "debugInfo": {
        "sharedDebugInfo": [
            {
                "name": "GOOGLE_SYSTEM_ACTION",
                "debugInfo": "Your query is handled by Google’s system actions"
            }
        ]
    },
    "visualResponse": {
        "visualElements": [
            {
                "displayText": {
                    "content": "Sorry, this action is not available in simulation"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

However in API.ai it does work, at least in the test area of the right side bar.

What step am I missing?

[image]

### New Problem, can't re-activate

I turned my test to inactive, and now can't re-activate it

[image]

Comment: The tutorial you are looking at is a bit old so the screens are now a bit different... Especially, when you are going to 'fulfillment' - Try to publish again your action on 'action on google' and then click 'test'. It should open the simulator and work for you.

Comment: Oh I didn't publish, but hit test.... doesn't publish push this to the Google store or make it open for review?

Comment: Sorry - I meant to 'enable' it with the switch on the top-right corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your Actions Integration settings:

1. Make sure you've selected intents properly.
2. Update your app.

Go to Simulator:

To start interacting with your test app:

> First pass: `Talk to <app-name>` **(compulsory)**.

Example:

1.[image: first]

---

2.[image: second]

Then you will be with your app and can use app commands in your triggered intents.

> And make sure you've filled app details properly in Overview page of AoG.

Comment: Ok I got the Active back, however how do you get the simulator to work? My original question?

Comment: I already mentioned: First pass: `Talk to <app-name>`. 
I'm updating to a bit explained answer.